# Global environment variable not available to bash command executed inside PHP

Tags: php, linux, bash, sudo

I'm trying to return the value of a global environment variable inside a bash script which is executed from inside PHP (run as sudo).

Running the command `printenv` from the bash script reveals that the global variable is not set. I understand sudo resets the environment.

Please consider the following setup;

**Define global environment var**

```
root@test:/# export HEY=hello
```

**Test existence of var**

```
root@test:/# printenv | grep HEY
HEY=hello
```

Please consider this PHP function

**PHP function**

```
function testAction() {

    define('TEST_CMD', '/usr/bin/sudo /usr/local/test/bin/');
    $command = 'bash_script';
    $query = TEST_CMD.$command;

    exec ($query, $output, $return_var);

    var_dump( $output );
    var_dump( $return_var );
    echo exec('whoami');

}
```

**Contents of `/etc/sudoers.d/admin`**

```
admin   ALL=(ALL)       ALL
admin   ALL=NOPASSWD:/usr/local/test/bin/*
```

**Contents of `/usr/local/test/bin/bash_script`**

```
#!/bin/bash
printenv
echo $HEY
exit
```

I have tried putting `Defaults   env_keep +="HEY"` inside `/etc/sudoers.d/admin` too but that doesn't appear to work either.

OS is ubuntu 14.04

Any ideas?

Comment: Where is the value of `HEY` supposed to be coming from? Are you running the `php` code from the shell session that ran `export HEY=hello`? `export` isn't magic. It doesn't affect anything but the current process (and thus the current processes children).

Comment: The PHP code is being run through the browser (nginx+php-fpm)

Comment: The export HEY=hello is being run from a script that runs inside an init.d call

Comment: So that `export` is only in effect for that `init.d` script and its children. So unless that `init.d` script is the one for nginx or php-fpm or whatever is running the php process that is running your script it doesn't have any effect on your script. Is it in such an init.d script?

Comment: I did wonder about that, but both nginx and php are being launched from the same init script